# Is this correct formatting

Tags: python, loops, tuples

I am trying to make sure my code is right

I am not sure if this is the right format

```
>>> month_name= [('Month 1 is January'),('Month 2 is February'),('Month 3 is March'),('Month 4 is April'),('Month 5 is May'),('Month 6 is June'),('Month 7 is July'),('Month 8 is August'),('Month 9 is September'),('Month 10 is October'),('Month 11 is November'),('Month 12 is December')]
>>> print(month_name)
['Month 1 is January', 'Month 2 is February', 'Month 3 is March', 'Month 4 is April', 'Month 5 is May', 'Month 6 is June', 'Month 7 is July', 'Month 8 is August', 'Month 9 is September', 'Month 10 is October', 'Month 11 is November', 'Month 12 is December']
```

this is what it has to come out like: 
Create a list (or tuple only, no dictionary) that contains the months of the year. ( do not hardcode the number) Create a loop to print the number and the months of the year from the list. The output should like this: Month 1 is January Month 2 is February …. …. Month 12 is December Optional Month 1 is January, Happy new year

Comment: Not sure how you expect us to know what is correct for a problem you haven't described.

Comment: this is what it has to come out like:

Comment: Create a list (or tuple only, no dictionary) that contains the months of the year. ( do not hardcode the number)
       Create a loop to print the number and the months of the year from the list. 
      The output should like this:

  Month 1  is  January

  Month 2 is  February

  ….

  ….

  Month 12 is December

Optional 
        Month 1 is January, Happy new year

Answer (score 0):

A pair of parentheses around an expression won't make a tuple. If you wanted to make one-element tuples, you need a trailing comma in the parentheses:

```
>>> month_name= [('Month 1 is January',),('Month 2 is February',),('Month 3 is March',),('Month 4 is April',),('Month 5 is May',),('Month 6 is June',),('Month 7 is July',),('Month 8 is August',),('Month 9 is September',),('Month 10 is October',),('Month 11 is November',),('Month 12 is December',)]
>>> month_name
[('Month 1 is January',), ('Month 2 is February',), ('Month 3 is March',), ('Month 4 is April',), ('Month 5 is May',), ('Month 6 is June',), ('Month 7 is July',), ('Month 8 is August',), ('Month 9 is September',), ('Month 10 is October',), ('Month 11 is November',), ('Month 12 is December',)]
>>>
```